# WordPress add Login/Logout to menu editor

Tags: wordpress, authentication, menu, themes, logout

Ok, so I found this code, which I modified to suit my needs. Btw, I'm using WooCommerce, which explains the "wc" in some of the function calls:

```
//Add login/logout link to primary menu
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_loginout_link', 10, 2 );
function add_loginout_link( $items, $args ) {
    if (is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'primary') {
        $items .= '<li><a href="'. wc_get_endpoint_url( 'customer-logout', '', wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) .'">Log Out</a></li>';
    }
    elseif (!is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'primary') {
        $items .= '<li><a href="'. wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) .'">Log In</a></li>';
    }
    return $items;
```

This adds the login/logout menu items, and they work fine. However, they're stuck at the end of the menu, at the moment. I'd like to be able to edit the position using the editor in wp-admin. The solution I thought of was to maybe just create login and logout pages, and use header location redirects with those lines of code in them to get to the proper URLs, but the issue I see with that is that there will always be a login item and logout, no matter what status the user is currently in. Would there maybe be a way to dynamically add a site-wide CSS rule to hide the opposite menu item, based on the log in status?

Or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best idea but you can try.
Create in wp-admin menu section new menu item like "Custom Link"

Log Out

http://www.example.com/account/customer-logout/

Log In

http://www.example.com/account/

And add a custom class to a WordPress menu item to manage visibility
For example, you will see "logged-in" class on the body of the page and hide "Log In" link or change it to "Account" with the same link.

Comment: By class, I assume you mean CSS class? How do I dynamically modify the CSS like that, depending on a user's logged-in state?

Comment: CSS class. 
Add class like this [link](http://sevenspark.com/how-to/how-to-add-a-custom-class-to-a-wordpress-menu-item) 
And you can operate on CSS (hide LogOut or LogIn)
For example: to LogIn item add class "user-guest" and in CSS add .logged-in .user-guest { display:none;} so logged in users will not see LogIn button

Comment: Oh wow, I did not realize that the body automatically adds a .logged-in class when the user is logged in. That's incredible. Ok, this definitely sounds like the easiest way to do it. I'm also not sure if it's the best idea, but I think it's better than my idea with the header redirects